# Protected cells in Workbook disables formatting tools on MS-Excel (openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

For my usecase I only want to protect some columns and therefore be able to use formatting and changing values of cells on unprotected columns only. To load my workbook, I use openpyxl. My code looks as follows:

```
wb = load_workbook('FILE_NAME.xlsx')
ws = wb['RELEASE_SHEET']
ws.protection.sheet = True

for col in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]:
    for cell in ws[col]:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)
```

This works perfectly fine and protects every cell in the columns A to I from formatting and changings.

Opening the excel-file on MS-Office, I can only change the values in the unprotected cells, which is good. However, I can not use any tools at all. Not even on non-protected cells to format them. The toolbar seems to be disabled and the worksheet does not react to format-shortcuts.

[image]

If I unprotect the Sheet it works again.

Do I need to load or save the sheet on another way? Or is there something wrong with the way I am protecting the cells?

Comment: When you enable protection for a worksheet, you protect all cells by default so your code will need to unprotect any cells you wish to be able to work with. You'll need to study the Excel documentation pretty carefully for this because it's fairly counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that you need to set it manually:

Simply use

```
wb = load_workbook('FILE_NAME.xlsx')
ws = wb['RELEASE_SHEET']
ws.protection.sheet = True
ws.protection.formatCells = False
```

formatCells set to false will enable the toolbar again.